# Why do I keep getting unique constraint violated?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table Doctor
(
    docID INTEGER,
    appointID INTEGER not null,
    regnum CHAR(6),   
    doc_name VARCHAR(40),
    doc_gender CHAR(1),
    qual VARCHAR(80),       

    primary key (docID),
    foreign key (appointID) references Appointment
);

INSERT INTO Doctor 
VALUES(1, 1, 'ABC001', 'Steven Arrow', 'M', 'Bachelor of Medicine  and Surgery, Deakin University, 1980');
```

I keep getting an error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (S3705969.SYS_C001160460) violated

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably because you already have a row that has `docID` equal to "1".

Comment: Most likely there is already a record with DocID=1 in this table. Run `SELECT * FROM Doctor where DocId=1` to check if such a record exists. There is `primary key (docID),` constraint that prevents from duplicates in ID column.

Answer (score 2):

You should allow Oracle to fill `docId` column using [`IDENTITY`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAHJHJC):

```
create table Doctor
(
docID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY not null ,
appointID   INTEGER ,
regnum  CHAR(6),   
doc_name    VARCHAR(40),
doc_gender  CHAR(1),
qual    VARCHAR(80),        
primary key (docID),
foreign key (appointID) references Appointment(column_name)  
);

INSERT INTO Doctor(col_names, ...)    --skip docID
VALUES( 1, 'ABC001', 'Steven Arrow', 'M',
      'Bachelor of Medicine  and Surgery, Deakin University, 1980');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the error that you get when you repeat a value for a primary key.  The best way to fix this is to use Oracle 12C+ and use a generated identity column for the primary key.

A relatively simple approach is to use a sequence *and be sure it is used for all inserts*:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE doctor_sequence;

INSERT INTO Doctor( . . . )
    VALUES(doctor_sequence.enxtval, 1, 'ABC001', 'Steven Arrow', 'M', 'Bachelor of Medicine  and Surgery, Deakin University, 1980');
```

The `. . .` is because you should explicitly list all the columns when doing an insert.

I should point out that when using sequences, the safest approach is to use insert triggers, so you are not depending on the application logic to use the sequence.  However, a trigger may not be necessary for what you are doing.  And, if you are using more recent versions of Oracle, then you can simply use a generated column.

Answer (score 0):

DB has probably created unique constraint on some column after you created a table or there is already a row with ID 1. Have you tried querying the table for all data? If it is empty before insertion than unique constraint shouldn’t be violated. Try `DESCRIBE DOCTOR` to see if there are any unique constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The `ORA-00001` message means you are inserting a duplicate value into a column. Looking at your `create table` statement we can guess that it will be DOC_ID so you must already have inserted a row with a DOC_ID = 1.

So why is the error message so enigmatic?

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (S3705969.SYS_C001160460) violated

The mysterious name is because you created the primary key without naming the constraint, so Oracle generated one for you; constraints aren't first class database objects (not like tables) but they still require names.

What you could do is name the constraint where you create it, e.g.

```
create table Doctor
(
   docID INTEGER,
   appointID   INTEGER ,
   regnum  CHAR(6),   
   doc_name    VARCHAR(40),
   doc_gender  CHAR(1),
   qual    VARCHAR(80),        
   constraint DOCTOR_PK primary key (docID),
   constraint DOCTOR_APPOINTMENT_FK foreign key (appointID) 
        references Appointment(column_name) 
);
```

But if you find yourself working with a schema which lacks names then you can use the data dictionary to discover what's going onL

```
select c.table_name
      , decode (c.constraint_type
                , 'P', 'Primary key'
                , 'U', 'Unique key'
                , 'R', 'Foreign key'
                , 'C', 'Check') as constraint_type
      , cc.column_name
from all_constraints c
      join all_cons_columns cc
      on cc.owner = c.owner
      and cc.table_name = c.table_name
      and cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
where c.owner = 'S3705969' 
and c.constraint_name = 'SYS_C001160460'
order by cc.position
/
```

---

Incidentally it seems like your foreign key is the wrong way round. One doctor has many appointments, so your APPOINTMENT table should have a column DOCTOR_ID with a foreign key referencing the DOCTOR table.